# Button focused state getting lost : Google TV

Tags: android, button, focus, google-tv, lost-focus

In my Google TV application, there are around 6 buttons with all that pressed, focused, enabled etc. states with them.

All buttons have got same pressed, focused, enabled etc. states in a xml file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/default_bt" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/default_bt" android:state_enabled="false" /> <!-- disabled -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/default_bt_hvr" android:state_focused="true"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/default_bt_hvr"/> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

Using Google TV remote, if I start moving to the left side, buttons shifting their focus and when I reach the leftmost button, focus remains on the leftmost button.

From that position (leftmost), if I start moving right, focus is coming till rightmost button but goes missing after that.

Is it accepted behavior or something wrong with it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not a general case.

So, I managed to bring the focus back with `view.requestFocus()` wherever required;

Comment: You may want to use requestFocusFromTouch() to always guarantee that focus will be set.  There are times where requestFocus() won't give you what you want.